# iCloud : how to manage iCloud deactivation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

I'm facing a problem concerning the iCloud synchronization process.

When a user decide to activate iCloud, the document stored locally in the app sandbox is moved to the local iCloud directory and then the file in the sandbox is deleted. This is done by the **setUbiquitous** method.

My problem arise if the user deactivates iCloud in the iPhone settings ( by switching off "iCloud documents and data save" ). In this case the iCloud directory is no more accessible and the app sandbox is void ( because it was deleted by the **setUbiquitous** method ). Therefore, the user lost all it's data...

One solution could be to always maintain a copy of the iCloud file in the app sandbox... but that seems quite a lot of work. There should be an easier way to do... Anyone has a better idea/solution ??

Thanks for reading ;)

Comment: I agree, this asymmetry seems like a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The files are not actually deleted and will be re-downloaded when iCloud is enabled again. Couldn't you just show a message with that information? In a way, that's similar to removing an email account in the settings app. The user probably expects that his/her emails are then deleted from the device, but are still available "in the cloud".

Comment: Yes but I don't want the user to be forced to activate iCloud again to retrieve its data !

Comment: If you don't want that, your only choice is to keep a local copy of the data in iCloud. Consider however that if every app would do that, it would double the amount of storage users need for their data.

Comment: Yes we are ok, It doesn't seem to have an alternative to the redundant local copy. Thank you ;)